# How does the Observer pattern reduce coupling?

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I understand how the Observer pattern works, but why is it that the Observer pattern reduces coupling between UI and business logic components in software design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) reduces coupling among its participants because it introduces an abstract type, Observer, between the Subject and its Observers.

Imagine a Model (the Subject in the Gang of Four/Wikipedia description, and the home of business logic) and a View (an Observer). Without Observer, the Model would need to call a method on the View whenever it changed. The Model would know the concrete class of View and be coupled to it, and to whatever UI-specific framework the View was a part of.

With Observer, the Model only knows about the type (abstract class or interface) Observer, so it is not coupled to the concrete View.